# I want to print "identifier":"OPTSTKHDFC25-08-2022PE1660.00" in python

Tags: python, json

I tried below code but it gave

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

```py
from nsepython import *
import pandas as pd
import json

positions = nse_optionchain_scrapper ('HDFC')

json_decode = json.dumps(positions,indent = 4, sort_keys=True,separators =(". ", " = "))

print(json_decode['data'][0]['identifier'])
```

Comment: Please learn about [code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

print(json_decode['filtered']['data'][0]['PE']['identifier'])

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> json_decode = json.dumps(positions,indent = 4, sort_keys=True,separators =(". ", " = "))

You can't build a JSON string (which is what `json.dumps` does) and then try to access part of the result as if it were the original data structure. Your `json_decode` is just a string, not a dict; as far as Python is concerned it has no structure beyond the individual characters that make it up.

If you want to access parts of the data, just use `positions` directly:

```
print(positions['data'][0]['identifier'])
```

You can encode just that bit to JSON if you like:

```
print(json.dumps(positions['data'][0]['identifier'])
```

but that's probably just a quoted string in this case.

So I'm not sure what your goal is. If you want to print out the JSON version of `positions`, great, just print it out. But the JSON form is for input and output only; it's not suitable for messing around with inside your Python code.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your response!! I got it.